# Summing using a case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am looking to roll up my numbers.

```
 SELECT 
     SORDERQ.SOHNUM_0,
     YQTYORD_0, 
     ORDINVNOT_0
 FROM LIVE.SORDER
 LEFT JOIN LIVE. SORDERQ ON SORDER.SOHNUM_0 = SORDERQ.SOHNUM_0
 WHERE SORDER.SOHNUM_0 = 'SC111-162420_19'
 AND ZBPSELECTION_0 <> ''
 AND YCROPYR_0 = '2019'
 AND SORDER.SALFCY_0 = '111'
```

[image]

I want to return 1 record per SOHNUM_0,the sum of YQTYORD_0 by SOHNUM_0 and ORDINVNOT_0.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to return 1 record per SOHNUM_0,the sum of YQTYORD_0 by SOHNUM_0 and ORDINVNOT_0.

Are you just looking for simple aggregation?

```
SELECT 
    q.SOHNUM_0,
    SUM(YQTYORD_0) SUM_YQTYORD_0, 
    ORDINVNOT_0
FROM LIVE.SORDER o
LEFT JOIN LIVE.SORDERQ q ON o.SOHNUM_0 = q.SOHNUM_0
WHERE 
    o.SOHNUM_0 = 'SC111-162420_19'
    AND o.SALFCY_0 = '111'
    AND ZBPSELECTION_0 <> '' 
    AND YCROPYR_0 = '2019' 
GROUP BY 
    q.SOHNUM_0, 
    ORDINVNOT_0
```

Note:

- I modified your query so it uses table aliases - this makes it shorter
- you should prefix all columns in the query with the table they belong to, to make your query unmabiguous and easier to understand